# Hyper-v pass to WMs web-server not throw external ip

Tags: web-server, hyper-v, external-ip

There is server with Hyper-v. We would like split them to several virtual machine's. Each machine has own web server. There is any solution pass to Webserver not throw external ip(buying them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - and it has nothing to do with VMs, it can be done in a single IIS server (or multiple ones). It's called Host Header : it enables your webserver to respond differently based on the website name that the client is asking for.

Comment: is Host header(IIS server) part of one of WM ?

Comment: It has been part of IIS since - hm - since 5.0 or something more than 10 years ago. Did you consider reading documentation? "Host Header IIS" is also a good term for google.

Comment: Even when using host headers, he still needs at least one public IP, otherwise there is never any traffic coming to his sites. If he has just one public IP and wants multiple VMs, he needs to map the external requests to different internal IPs

Comment: @PeterHahndorf -of course, I was reading his question as if he needed one IP per site. Without a doubt, he has to have at least one public IP and a gateway device that can NAT.